# Growl with guard and spork fails silently on OS 10.6.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, spork, guard, growl

I get no Growl notifications when tests pass or fail. I've gone through all the setup guides I can find.

**Details**

I run `guard` and it starts Spork fine:

```
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
```

When I change a spec file, everything seems OK:

```
Running: spec/unit/category_spec.rb
Running tests with args ["--color", "--format", "progress", "--format", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "--require", "/Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-rspec-0.5.2/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "spec/unit/category_spec.rb"]...
.

Finished in 0.2063 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
Done.
```

But... nothing from Growl.

**What I've Tried**

- Ticked Guard in the Applications tab in Growl pref pane
- Installed latest Growl for Snow Leopard - V1.2.2
- Growl is started and working OK - I enable iTerm and I get notifications from that fine.
- Added `rb-fsevent`, `growl` and `growl_notify` to gem file and ran bundle install
- Installed Growl Notify package from the Growl Downloads page.
- Restarted my Mac

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "spork", "> 0.9.0.rc"
  gem "guard-spork"
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'growl_notify'
  gem 'growl'
end
```

**Update**

By complete chance I found that when I removed the `--drb` option from the guard file:

Before:

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => "--drb"  do
```

After:

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => ""  do
```

Growl started working. But when I do this, the tests take ages to run again.

**Growl works OR tests are fast ...but not both!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the penny dropped, completely by accident.

I had the following line in my Guardfile:

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => "--drb" do
    ....
end
```

The problem was the `--drb` switch - once I removed it, all was well:

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => "" do
    ....
end
```

Now Growl notifies me immediately when tests pass/fail. Hurrah!

Comment: The only problem now is that the tests take ages to run again, presumably because rspec isn't running using the --drb option and not finding spork. This is so irritating - it looks like I can get Growl working OR I can have fast tests, but not both!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem - very annoying!

Comment: Nope. Still using it with fast tests and no Growl notifications. It is indeed *very* annoying!

Comment: Well, I finally fixed this on my machine, but not the way I wanted to. Updated to OSX Lion and paid for growl so I could install growlnotify. worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to [get growl notify](http://growl.info/downloads) to get it to work with my system. There are other options available, but I can't find the website or post that lists them. That was the easiest for me to setup. Growl notify is different than Growl.

Comment: https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/60 discusses this issue and also https://github.com/scottdavis/growl_notify/issues/6

Comment: From what I read we're dealing with two different things. I am using the growl gem, but I had to install the growl notify software for it to work. My understanding is the growl notify allows the CLI to activate growl. Is this not the case?

Comment: I've downloaded the Growl Notify package and installed it, but I'm already using the growl_notify gem. Either way I still get nothing when the tests run again. Everything seems to be fine, Growl just doesn't show anything when a test fails/passes.